# Security risks handling OpenID Connect id_token and access_token between Mobile Client and Server (Google sign-in)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid-connect

I am looking at allowing users to login to my mobile application using Google. If the user is already logged into Google on their device, I don't want them to have to re-enter their username and password (a 'native login experience'). Once the user is logged in, they can access private resources on my server. To achieve this, I am using the OpenID Connect [implicit flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth). This is how I understand the flow to be:

1. A user is using my mobile client app (ios or android) and chooses to sign in with Google.
2. My client app (using Googles ios or android SDK) obtains an [access_token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) and [id_token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) (assuming the user has the Google+ app installed, is already logged into it and has given permission to my app).
3. My client app sends the access_token and/or id_token to my server.
4. My server [verifies the access_token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) and/or [verifies the id_token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken)
5. Using either token, my server maps the google user to a user in my own database.
6. My server creates its own new security token and returns it to my client app.
7. My client app uses the new security token in subsequent requests to my server to access private resources.

**Questions:**

Is this the correct flow to use to login if I want to give the user a 'native login experience'?

Assuming I am following all of googles guidelines (e.g using SSL, sending tokens in header or POST data, verifying the tokens correctly)...

What vulnerabilities are there with sending the access_token from the client?

What vulnerabilities are there with sending the id_token from the client?

What other security risks are there with this flow?

This seems like it is a very common use case. Is this what most applications are doing to achieve 'native authentication' with Google? Examples of apps would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a complete answer but a thought of mine on this: I think there's a potential risk on sending access_token, since server could store it (increasing theft risk) and/or send it elsewhere without SSL then exposing access_token, isn't it? Since Google Guidelines (such as SSL usage) are not mandatory (can't be, there's no way to check it) every potential use out of that guides is dangerous. Not a risk you can avoid, but a risk anyway. I've seen no guideline on server storage of access_token either.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The server wouldn't be storing the access_token or sending it anywhere without using SSL. I was more looking for potential issues with the server accepting the access_token or id_token without first initiating the flow e.g. is it vulnerable to replay attacks? Should the client first request a nonce[link](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) generated on my server and then send it to my server with the id_token for validation

Answer (score 0):

Any time the client passes an ID Token to the server (which includes all ID Tokens coming from the implicit flow), the server MUST fully validate it.

Google has some docs on how to validate ID Tokens, see:

- [Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)
- [iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth)
- [Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

If the server is also handling *access tokens* directly from the client (i.e. not using the server flow), then it should validate that they belong to the correct user too. The ID Token claim `at_hash` can be used to [verify that the access token does belong to the same user identified in the ID Token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30356460/72176).

If you use the server (aka 'code') flow on the other hand, then the server is handed the `code` from the client, and exchanges it directly at the token endpoint, presenting its client secret to do so. ID Tokens and Access tokens obtained in this manner do not need to be verified, as they come directly from Google.